Failed to start ContainerManager open /proc/sys/kernel/panic: permission denied
I tryed to set up a Cubernetes Cluster on a STRATO vServer.
Every time execute kubeadm init ... kubelet crashs with the Message
"Failed to start ContainerManager open /proc/sys/kernel/panic: permission denied"
I searched the web for a solution for two days but found nothing.
Has anyone a hint for me?

This is probably an issue with the VPS provider's restricted environment. See this GitHub Issue for more info.
